# How to assign a variable to another variable without referencing to each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, variables, hash

I want to assign variable to another variable with exactly no reference.
Say, I have a variable `hash`.
`hash = {points: []}`

Now I assign it to another variable `abc`.
`abc = hash`

Then I change value of `points` key of `hash`.

`hash[:points] << 10` #=> hash = {points: [10]}

`hash[:points] << 20` #=> hash = {points: [10, 20]}

It also changes value of `abc`: #=> `{points: [10, 20]}`

I have already tried `dup` and `clone` while assiging `hash` into `abc`, but not working.

I want `abc` to remain unchanged even `hash` is changed.
abc  #=> {points: []}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `deep copy`. Try this:

```
hash = { points: [] }
abc = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))

abc[:points] = 10
p abc
#-> { :points => 10 }
p hash
#-> { :points => [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = { points: [] }

abc = transform_values(@:dup)
hash[:points] << 1 << 2

hash #=> {:points=>[1, 2]} 
abc  #=> {:points=>[]}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).